# "Send and Download" in Postman Collection Runner

Tags: file, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using postman since few day. I have a lot of request to test in a raw. I'm asking if on postman an option like "Send and Download" for one request exist in the Collection Runner to save all the file from GET request in my collection.